# Is there a good DNS server I can install on Windows 7 for a LAN?

Tags: windows-7, networking, software-rec, dns, home-networking

I have a few computers on my LAN, and now I'm getting tired of remembering the IP addresses all the time, so I would like to start using DNS names on my LAN.

I have a heterogeneous network with Windows 7, Ubuntu, Mac OS X and Android.

Is there a free DNS server software that is easy to setup on Windows 7, preferably with a graphical user interface or maybe web-interface?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe [MaraDNS](http://www.maradns.org/download.html) could be of some use for you, here's a [tutorial](http://blog.mixu.net/2009/10/14/how-to-setup-a-lan-dns-server-using-maradns-under-windows-7/) on how to set it up.

Comment: It's not a graphical solution :(

Answer (score 27):

1. Consider placing [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) on your router, it uses `dnsmasq` with a `hosts` file.

   This way, you won't lose energy costs on having to run that computer solely for DNS...
2. If your router doesn't [support](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Netgear) it, check out these DNS servers for Windows:

   - The most widely used DNS server, [BIND](http://www.isc.org/software/bind), has a `ntbind` variant.
   - [Microsoft DNS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb629410.aspx) is included with Windows Server, if you can run that, perhaps virtualized.
   - [Simple DNS Server](http://www.simpledns.com/) really follows the KISS principle; Keep It Stupidly Simple. It's trial though...
   - [PowerDNS](http://www.powerdns.com/content/home-powerdns.html), a Dutch DNS server that fits home DNS hosting.
   - [MaraDNS](http://www.maradns.org/) only has partial support ([according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software#cite_note-ntbind-45pedia)), but is a security-aware DNS server.
   - [Posadis](http://posadis.sourceforge.net/) is GPL licensed, compatible with BIND files.
   - [Unbound](http://unbound.net/) is BSD licensed, uses modular components.
   - [Cisco Network Registrar](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/netmgtsw/ps1982/) is proprietary, fits a larger company if you want support.

   If you have the money, Simple DNS Server looks really nice. Or perhaps Microsoft DNS...

   Else try an open source DNS server like BIND, PowerDNS, MaraDNS, Posadis or Unbound.
3. If you have static IPs, placing the same `hosts` file on every computer is a cheap solution.

Comment: Thanks, I think Simple DNS Server looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Jonas: Oh, on a second check it seems to be a trial. I've also added a third option...

Comment: PowerDNS does not support Windows

Answer (score 5):

What I have done in the past is install Windows 2003 in a virtual machine with the DNS/DHCP server running on it.  If you don't have access to Windows 2003 you could install any number of Linux OS's in the VM and use that as a DHCP/DNS server.

Does your router not have DNS support? I run Tomato on my router and I'm able to assign static IPs through the interface and access all my computers by hostname.

Comment: Interesting. No, my parents have a cheap Netgear router without DNS functionality.

Comment: @Jonas: You can install firmware on your router; for example, I've listed DD-WRT in my answer. These firmwares come with compatibility list, so you can [easily look up NetGear](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#Netgear) to see whether your device is supported. Tomato isn't as widely supporting though, but you could try to give DD-WRT a shot...