# How to run a dns server on a home network?

Tags: windows, dns, domain

I have a typical home network. Cable modem connects to router, everything else connects to that router. I have manually assigned IP addresses to MAC addresses of the various devices that connect to the router.

Those devices all have their own machine names, but there is no gaurantee that any of those names can be resolved. I don't know why.

This is not active directory/ldap, and this has nothing to do with user permissions. I just want to be able to say that the computer at 192.168.1.101 has the domain name DESKTOP and 192.168.1.101 has the domain name MEDIASERVER, etc etc etc.

My media server is running Windows 7 and is the only machine that is on 24/7.

My Router is a linksys router using linksys firmware. It is not easily hackable with dd-wrt unfortunately.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/337763/is-there-a-good-dns-server-i-can-install-on-windows-7-for-a-lan

Comment: @SachinShekhar this really isn't a dupe.  The other is asking what software, while this is asking how.

Answer (score 0):

### Router

In general if your router is capable of handing out IP-addresses by DHCP it is probably capable of acting as a DNS server and may have an option for adding statically defined IP-addresses to it's known list (I have a BT branded 2wire router that has this feature - I use it to enter names and addresses of statically configured PCs that don't use DHCP - the router provides DNS service that can resolve the names of these statically configured PCs).

### Other non-PC device

If you have a home NAS or other "always-on" device, that would be a good candidate for providing DNS

### PC

You can runs something like BIND (or preferably perhaps, something simpler) on any Linux or Windows PC. This isn't ideal if the PC is a personal desktop and other computers rely on it being turned on.