# Looking for easiest, most simple solution to run a customised DNS Server for my local network on Windows 7.

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns

I need to forward some websites, such as http://testing.server/ to an fixed IP address on my local network. I can do this easily on one computer using the hosts file. However, I need this to work for all machines on my network.

I think the best way to do this will be to setup my own DNS Servers and add the custom DNS settings there.

However, I'm looking for the simplest way possible to do this - I really don't want to spend hours setting up Unix Servers and running tricky terminal based scripts just to do this!

My server is a standard Windows 7 machine.

My dream would be a nice simple windows program with a GUI where I could input my ISP's DNS server and it would use those records, unless I had specifically set up my own DNS for a domain to use instead. If it had a web based admin system that was accessible from another computer on the network that would be even better.

Does anyone know of anything that can do this? Many thanks indeed.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before http://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there might be a less command prompt based, and more GUI solution these days, but unless someone posts another suggestion I will go down the Bind route. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 does not come with a DNS server, only Microsoft Server Operating Systems come with a builtin DNS server.

You can install other DNS server software on your Windows 7, check out [Is there a good DNS server I can install on Windows 7 for a LAN?](https://superuser.com/questions/337763/is-there-a-good-dns-server-i-can-install-on-windows-7-for-a-lan).

If there are not too many computers in your network (at least I guess so since you are using Windows 7 as server), then you might just stick to a hosts file based solution.