# Redirect website url to a different url of that website (hosts)

Tags: redirection, hosts-file

I am unsure if this is possible. I am trying to use the Window's `hosts` file to redirect the address `www.youtube.com` to `music.youtube.com`.

When I `ping youtube.com`, I am returned with this IP:

- 172.217.12.14

When I `ping music.youtube.com` I get this IP:

- 172.217.1.206

In the `hosts` file, I type the following:

```
172.217.1.206 www.youtube.com
172.217.1.206 music.youtube.com
```

I would like to re-direct the exact route of `www.youtube.com` to `music.youtube.com` who's IP is `172.217.1.206`

So far this lets the YouTube website load normally with the `www.youtube.com` URL. I would like it to re-direct me to `music.youtube.com` **WITHOUT** blocking or restricting video-specific YouTube URLs. 
How do I make the `hosts` file or something to work this way?

(I don't care if I can access a YouTube video's URL manually, I just want to re-route the main domain name: `www.youtube.com`.)

EDIT:
For more clarification, I would like to type this address: `www.youtube.com` in the browser and be re-directed to `music.youtube.com`. If I type: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ it will load Youtube normally without the re-direct. I would like the re-direct to only happen with the URL `www.youtube.com`.

Comment: not really sure what you exactly want, could you give a specific example?

Comment: Review edit for more clarification.

Comment: no this is not possible using the host file (see my answer). if using the host file isn't your only option, there are other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately, this is not possible using the host file. That is not how DNS resolution works. To put it in simple terms, if you redirect the domain `www.youtube.com` to a certain IP address via the host file it will redirect all traffic. Regardless of what comes after the `www.youtube.com/`.

There are plenty of other solutions though, for example installing a web server and using htaccess for the redirect (see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/58762/how-to-redirect-root-and-only-root-via-htaccess) on StackExchange or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239930/redirect-root-and-only-root-url-to-another-domain)).

A redirection service in combination with the host file might work as well, [see here](https://www.wikihow.com/Redirect-a-URL).

The last option I can think of is using 3rd party software, for example installing your own local DNS server, like [SANS](http://posadis.sourceforge.net/sans) or one of [many others](https://superuser.com/questions/337763/is-there-a-good-dns-server-i-can-install-on-windows-7-for-a-lan). It might be worth checking your internet router's options as well.